# MySQL Results Are Exact Opposite of What I Need

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following is my Database Design course question that I cannot find a way to get the results that I want.

-- ME.9 For game 4, if I land on one of the first ten spots, which ones can I buy? What is the price?

--      List order_site, site name, price

--      Answer: (4 rows, 3 columns)

```
    SELECT site.order_site, site.site_label, site.price
    FROM game_player
    JOIN game
        ON game.game_id = game_player.game_id
    JOIN game_player_owns_site
        ON game_player_player_id = game_player.player_id
    JOIN site
        ON site_order_site = order_site
    WHERE game.game_id = 4
        AND site.order_site <= 10
        AND site.is_ownable = 1;
```

The results are a virtual table that is 2x3 but it should be 4x3 and not include the results that are currently being displayed. The database generator is the following: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VwQKEqkP)

Comment: Where's the table structure? Sample input?  Sample output?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sample input is the Pastebin file that will generate the sample database and the output, as stated above, is a 2x3 table instead of the 4x3 table that I'm looking for. @Eric

Comment: @ChristopherBilger, "sample output," means that you need to create an example of what the resulting 4x3 table should look like. Additionally, you should revise your question to be defined as a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting the whole database and asking for a solution is a bit much (even though it IS a very small database).

Comment: As a simplified solution, you should probably define it as `SELECT ... FROM site ... LEFT INNER JOIN ...`

Comment: build a working example at some place like rextester.com or sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com (your pastebin cant be used "as is", can't "use" a nominated schema) then we might be able to follow your problem, but it is almost certainly data related, so unless we can easily see the data it's unlikely we can help.